# Handle Abort/Kill/Connection Close from Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a MySQL stored procedure that does maintenance on large tables, and runs every night.
Unfortunately, due to reasons beyond my control, the running SP sometimes stops unexpectedly (due to "kill" by another admins or dropped connections).

Is there a way to "catch" those situations from within my SP and update a table (e.g. an activity log or maintenance audit table) when this happens?

I tried:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING, SQLEXCEPTION
```

...and other specific ERRORs and SQLSTATEs:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1078, 1080, 1152, 1159, 1161, 1184, 1317, 3169, SQLSTATE '08S01'
```

but non of them seem to catch when aborting or killing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DECLARE EXIT HANDLER` is for times your query terminates normally, something like clicking on *shutdown* button in windows. But kill process by another admin is something like reset PC by hand or power outage, So there is no time to do anything.

A good way to find these situations is investigating MySQL logs. If you cannot access to logs, try to do that by yourself. For example create a log table (include *id, sp_name, start_time,end_time*) and insert a record every time SP starts. You can do it by inserting timestamp and SP name at the beginning of SP. At the end of SP, you can update this record by inserting a timestamp for end_time. Every record with a start_time and without end_time means the contained SP name is killed by others after start_time time.

Comment: I have already created such table. I was just hoping I could somehow updated the "end_time" automatically if the SP is killed or aborted.

Comment: There is no end in your process! you cannot add exact end_time. But you can create and update an update_time periodically (for example each minute) to find approximate kill time. Something like Journaling in DB and Filesystem.

Comment: The "exact" end time is not too interesting - more interesting is whether a previous instance is still running (because it was triggered manually earlier) or not, to figure out if I should just leave it running and quit, or start a new instance.

I ended up putting the mysql CONNECTION_ID() in the tracking table, and checking when the SP starts if this connection is still active (in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST) to determine if a previous instance is still running or terminated - it just feels like there's a simpler, more elegant solution.

Comment: Accepted as answer as this pointed me in the right direction.